# how to detect the Temperature hot spot from thermal image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I want to detect temperature from thermal images and plot/mark the area where the temperature is detected above the threshold.
Thermal Image will be input (attached) and expected output --> mark the area where temperature is above threshold.

[image]

Comment: what is your question? ... what have you tried?

Comment: I have thermal images. I want to detect and plots the area of the image where a temperature is more than a specifies threshold. How can I do in python 3.7

Comment: Please try to improve your question by adding representative images, and your latest/greatest attempt at coding it yourself. Thank you.

Comment: false-color images are nearly useless for this. you need the source data, which contains actual temperature values (grayscale). *do not* just convert the false-color to grayscale. that's not how that works. if you absolutely have to, you could grab the color scale (OCR the low and high values) and lookup the false-color values back into linear temperature values. don't worry if that makes no sense to you.

Comment: Is the colour-scale on the right hand side always exactly the same colours in all the images you have to analyse? And are the  `29` below it and `140` above it always fixed at those exact numbers - unvarying?

Comment: @MarkSetchell color scale is varying with images.

Comment: Ok, that makes the problem harder. You would need to locate the colour-bar on each image, and OCR the numbers below and above to establish lower and upper limits. Then interpolate between them to find the position in your colour-bar corresponding to your threshold. Then you need to determine all colours above that limit from the colour-bar. Then find those colours in the image. I doubt anyone will want to do that on StackOverflow - you are probably looking at paying someone if it is beyond your own skills.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, FLIR defines thermal palettes in a way no OCR will be required.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question and it does look like I can at least help with feasibility analysis.

First of all thermal palettes are [defined in a proper way](https://www.flir.com/discover/ots/outdoor/your-perfect-palette/) so there is an exact temperature-color mapping:

[image]

Which means if you know a threshold you know the color (some interpolation will be needed as Mark pointed out). Your example is too small, so I'll use another one.

I have three thresholds defined (as well as a color mapping threshold being used with delta_E), so here is the result:

[image]

It is not a problem to add additional threshold:

[image]

Let's use another example:

[image]

So, I'd say everything is pretty straightforward:

1. use thermal palette to map temperature
2. use any flavour of delta_E and similarity threshold to properly map colors
3. do a simple color-based segmentation